Grids are not visible in QGIS map layout

Grids are not applying or visible properly. Some thick numbers are appearing on the left side of the grid, but I don't know how to make them look normal.

Which CRS are you working with? Have you tried changing the grid spacing?

1m is too small a step

Look at these settings:

The grid is spaced by an interval of 1 map unit in X and Y. If the Map CRS is metres, for example if its UTM or Web Mercator, the grid lines will be one metre apart. The mess on your map edges is QGIS trying to draw things every metre...
Increase the X and Y interval (eg to 10,000 for 10 km) or change the CRS or Map Units so that the X and Y interval represent something close to what you want your grid to show.
